# what is the difference between 'grid.size()' and 'grid[0].size()' in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, grid, 2d

I have question in C++ 2D array. what is the difference between `grid.size()` and `grid[0].size()` in C++ in the code below?

```
public:
int minPathSum(vector<vector<int>>& grid) {
    for(int i = 0; i < grid.size(); i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < grid[0].size(); j++) {
            if(i == 0 && j == 0) continue;
            int tp = 1e9;
            if(i > 0) tp = min(tp, grid[i-1][j]);
            if(j > 0) tp = min(tp, grid[i][j-1]);
            grid[i][j] += tp;
        }
    return grid[grid.size()-1][grid[0].size()-1];
};
```

Comment: FYI -- If `grid` or `grid[0]` are empty, the `return` value invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Do you know what `grid[0]` means? And do you know what the `size()`-function does?

Comment: `grid.size()` returns the number of `vector<int>`s contained by `grid`.   `grid[0].size()` returns the number of `int`s in `grid[0]`  (where `grid[0]` is the first `vector<int>` in `grid`).     If `grid.size()` is zero, `grid[0]` does not exist, so evaluating `grid[0].size()` would give undefined behaviour.

Comment: The `return grid[grid.size()-1][grid[0].size()-1]` WILL give undefined behaviour if either `grid.size()` or `grid[0].size()` are zero.

Comment: Mathematically, `grid.size() - grid[0].size()`.

Comment: Similar to the difference between the number of houses on my block, and the number of bedrooms in my house.

Comment: What is the difference between "how big is my house" and "how big is my living room"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grid[0]` returns the first row of this two-dimensional `vector`  so `grid[0].size()` returns size of first row of that matrix and `grid.size()` return number of rows in the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

`grid.size()` is the size of the outer vector.

`grid[0].size()` is the size of the 1st inner vector of the outer vector.

Answer (score 1):

`grid.size()` is the number of row of the grid ( **outer vector size**).

`grid[i].size()` is the number of element for the ith row of the grid ( **inner vector size**).